# How to Create Advanced Flex custom components library

Tags: apache-flex

I want to create a custom component library. the components are customize-able during creation time. means like Accordion or TabNavigator, when we drag and drop the Accordion in flash builder it

```
<mx:Accordion x="38" y="167" width="200" height="200">
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Accordion Pane 1">
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:Accordion>
```

look there is two tags came at a time mx:Accordion and s:NavigatorContent how it happens. how can i create a component like this.

I want to create a component of container with three buttons. after i drag component into flash builder it should editable mean its tag must look like this

```
<local:container  x="38" y="167" width="200" height="200">
    <s:button width="10" height="10" />
    <s:button width="10" height="10" />
    <s:button width="10" height="10" />
</local:container>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to add additional tags when the user drags your custom component into Flash Builder you'll have to write an extension for your component and configure it within a `design.xml` file.

Here are a few links to get you started:

- [Flash Builder Design View extension FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/design-view-extensions-faq.html)
- [Extending Flex Builder](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2008-develop/extending-flex-builder-by-david-zuckerman-and-mike-morearty/)
- [Design View Extensibility Kit for Flex 4.5](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/extensibility/DesignViewExtKitReadme.htm)

Comment: +1 b/c that's the first time I've seen anything official article from Adobe about the design.xml file.  I think you're on the right track, with the Flash Builder extension since he wants to drag out a single component and have the IDe create multiple components.  I'm not sure if design.xml is needed to accomplish his task, though.

Comment: Yes, that FAQ is quite new (August 2011). I don't think it's possible to do this without design.xml. However, since I've never done this myself I'm not sure if you can create multiple components with a `<designExtension>` or a `<componentInserter>`. My guess is that one needs to create a Java class that implements `com.adobe.flexbuilder.mxmlmodel.components.IComponentInserter` and register that in design.xml

Comment: In my experiences--which are less complicated than what this poster asked for--the design.xml just defines the name of the folder that the components show up as in the component explorer.  Otherise they show up in the default "Custom Components" folder.  I'll have to read this article in depth. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First You want to understand one thing, that is creation of custom components is to simplify the tags. Though the flash builder also won't supports such kind of thing. The custom components child can be created internally by overriding some methods in it, which depends upon the base class you inherit.

Creation of Custom component will lead only to

```
<local:container  x="38" y="167" width="200" height="200">
</local:container>
```

Though you can add child in it by manually or internally.